# Linux Major and Minor Number

Tags: linux

I got to know that linux has major and minor number. But, now my question is, is there any command or way to find what are the major number and minor number being used for which device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`ls -l` will list it.

```
$ ls -l /dev/urandom
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root      1,   9 Sep 27 20:59 /dev/urandom
```

1 is the major number, 9 is the minor

Answer (score 0):

you may try `uname -a` to list all the info. If you only need the kernel version, `uname -r`.

Answer (score 0):

Majors and minors are documented here: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devices.txt
But I don't know to what extend this still does apply. Especially minors are allocated dynamically today, AFAIK. I don't know if that follows any particular system.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is /dev/sda1, then try:

```
stat /dev/sda1
```

You should get output looking like this:

```
  File: ‘/dev/sda1’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 1217        Links: 1     Device type: 8,1
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
```

The "Device: 5h/5d" are the major and minor number respectively for the device.

Hope this helps.